# Completion of the loading animation

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a loader that should play an animation when loading data. I want to get the animation completion effect.

For example, if the data is loaded for 1 second and the animation lasts for 2 seconds, then the animation should be played for 2 seconds. And if the data is loaded within 3 seconds, then 2 full animation cycles of 2 seconds should be played.

I tried to do so, but got an endless animation:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { useAppSelector } from '../../hooks/useRedux';
import './style.css';

const Loader = () => {
    const isLoading = useAppSelector((state) => state.appSlice.isLoading);
    const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadingAnimation = () => {
            setAnimate(true);

            setTimeout(() => {
                if (isLoading) { // for some reason always TRUE
                    loadingAnimation();
                } else {
                    setAnimate(false);
                }
            }, 1610);
        };

        if (isLoading) {
            loadingAnimation();
        }
    }, [isLoading]);

    return (
        <div className='loader'>
            <ul className='loader__items'>
                <li className={`${animate && 'loader__item-1'}`}></li>
                <li className={`${animate && 'loader__item-2'}`}></li>
                <li className={`${animate && 'loader__item-3'}`}></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Loader;
```

Tell me pls how to write this logic correctly.

css:

```
.loader {
    display: flex;

    height: 22px;
}

.loader__items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    width: 100%;
}

.loader ul li {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin: 2.5px;

    background-color: #47535d;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.loader__item-1,
.loader__item-2,
.loader__item-3 {
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: jump;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.loader__item-2 {
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.loader__item-3 {
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes jump {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    50% {
        transform: translateY(-5px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add styles.css file

Comment: Added, but I don't think there will be anything interesting